# Uploading Images in Android using FTP

Tags: android, ftp, proguard

I have a little question, which is really confusing me..

i am developing an Android application that can upload images to server using SimpleFTP library..

is it secure?, since the server information is provided in the Android code to be able to upload.

Any great information can be provided?

Thanks

Comment: No, generally speaking methods like this are not secure, as the credentials can easily be extracted from the application package or by monitoring the data in transit.  Thus it reduces to the standard "don't trust the client" rule - you cannot assume that your authorized client will be the only thing managing to interact with the server.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the great info, so you suggest to use a third party like a php file to receive the images and then upload it to the server?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but having something well-armored on the server which validates uploads sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Yes, but i wont validate uploads.. i want to hide the server info(such as username or password) from the client (if decoded the apk file).

Comment: You will have trouble hiding it in a way that can't be discovered by decompiling.  And as long as you are using anything remotely resembling standard FTP, someone could just extract that information by monitoring the network traffic anyway.

Comment: Exactly.. Thank you @ChrisStratton for your precious information and your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use public/private key authentication.
Take a look at Reliable example of how to use SFTP using public private key authentication with Java for more help.